# Heap-buffer-overflow runtime error when returning a dynamically allocated block

Tags: arrays, c, return, runtime-error, malloc

I recently started programming in C and ran into the problem of returning an array. When i try to return the array i get a heap-buffer-overflow runtime error.

Here is my code

```
int* getConcatenation(int* nums, int numsSize, int* returnSize){
    int *ans;
    ans=(int*)malloc(numsSize * sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
        ans[i]=nums[i];
        ans[i+numsSize]=nums[i];
    }
    free(ans);
    return ans;
}
```

Error

```
AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60200000003c at pc 0x55780cb25d30 bp 0x7ffd83067af0 sp 0x7ffd83067ae0
WRITE of size 4 at 0x60200000003c thread T0
    #2 0x7fabeed390b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x60200000003c is located 0 bytes to the right of 12-byte region [0x602000000030,0x60200000003c)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fabef97ebc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #3 0x7fabeed390b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00 04 fa fa 00[04]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==44==ABORTING
```

Changed code:

This is my code now but it still doesn't work

```
int* getConcatenation(int* nums,
                      int numsSize, 
                      int* returnSize)
{
    int *ans;
    ans=malloc(2*numsSize * sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0;i<numsSize;i++)
    {
        ans[i]=nums[i];
        ans[i+numsSize]=nums[i];
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: `ans[i+numsSize]=nums[i];`  you write outside of the bounds of the array

Comment: What do you think `free(ans); return ans;` does?

Comment: @Clifford It is encouraging by introducing an intrigue :)

Comment: ;-) @EugeneSh. Now maybe but in months later, when searching for AddressSanitizer issues, less useful to the community

Comment: Generic title: "I program in C, face this problem. and would be glad to know the solution." @Clifford

Comment: @Fe2O3 : yes, that was my point. Not sure what point you are making?

Comment: I hesitate to fix the title it for you, but suggest "_heap-buffer-overflow runtime error when returning a dynamically allocated block._", and forget all that "thanks in advance" nonsense, up-vote and/or accept useful answers to show appreciation.

Comment: @Clifford Just a bit of humour for a slow day. To which handful of SO [c] questions would this generic title not apply?

Comment: @Fe2O3 : Sorry, it's been a long day.  Understood.

Comment: What is the `returnSize` parameter for?  You do nothing with it.  Telling us code does not work is insufficient.  You have to say what you expected and what actually happened.  I suspect that the problem in question is solved and your updated code has a different issue (possibly in the calling code), so should not be included in this question.  Avoid declaring an initialised pointer, only to immediately assign it.  Prefer: 
`int* ans = malloc(2*numsSize * sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access:

```
ans[i+numsSize]=nums[i];
```

is way beyond the bounds of the allocated space.  You would need;

```
ans = malloc(2 * numsSize * sizeof(int))
```

You *can* return `ans`.  What you cannot do is access the memory it points to because you returned it to the heap with `free()`.  That makes it available for reuse.

Even if the `free()` were removed, it is an ill-advised pattern in most cases in any event.  By allocating memory inside a function, you would be relying on the caller knowing that the memory must be `free`'d.  It is better generally to have the allocation in the same scope as the release (as you have done, but in the wrong scope).  A more idiomatic pattern is to have the caller provide the memory and pass a pointer into the function.  That way the memory need not even be dynamically allocated, it is in the control of the caller.

`malloc()` returns a `void*` it need not be cast and is poor practice to do so.

Comment: Disagree with “it is an ill-advised pattern”. Many, _many_ extant functions in all kinds of libraries will give you a pointer to data you can play with and expect you to free it, either with `free()` directly or by calling a deallocation function. `strdup()` is an example of something in the standard libc. `malloc()` is the ur-example.

Comment: I changed the memory allocator and removed free() and still my code is not finished. It does not return anything.

Comment: @Dúthomhas It occurring _many_ times does not make it a good idea, and of course the fact that it occurs frequently, clearly many will disagree (though they may also be the ones with leaky, buggy code).  Perhaps it is my 33 year background in embedded systems that forms my point of view.  Yes`strdup()` is an example, and also the cause of numerous memory leak bugs.  The thing with `malloc()` is that it advertises its behaviour in its naming, and also the standard library is meticulously documented and unchanging in its behaviour.

Comment: @ДенисМороз : I cannot comment on unseen code.  All the issues above address flaws in your code.  If you now have different code with different errors then that is for a different question.  Clearly it returns _something_.  Only `void` functions return _nothing_.

Comment: I added the new code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ДенисМороз Does it fail in the same way? If not, it is different question and should be posted as a new question with the new behaviour.

Comment: @Clifford Yes, this is a new question, unfortunately, I won't be able to post a new question for the next three days, so I'll post it here. The code doesn't throw errors, but the code doesn't work and I don't get an array.